# How can i force Tinymce to wrap all content inside paragraphs?

Tags: javascript, editor, tinymce, rte

I initialize tinymce using `forced_root_block: 'p',` (this usually works fine).
The problem i am facing seems to be a special case. **I use Firefox.**
When i press `ctrl+a` and when all contetn is marked press one single letter (in example 'd') a closer inspection using firbug shows

```
<body ...>d</body>
```

If i push a second letter the editors content gets wrapped into a paragraph.

I need to style the editors content using css and paragraphs, but when there is no paragraph i am not able to style the content and the user could get irritated.
**How can i solve this issue?**

Comment: Which versions of TinyMCE and firefox?  I'm not seeing any issues with TinyMCE 3.3.9, or 3.4b3 on firefox 3.6.13 on OSX.

Comment: i am using version 3.3.7, firefox 3.6.13 on windows xp

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your tinymce config:

```
forced_root_block : "p",
force_br_newlines : false,
force_p_newlines : true,
```